# intellij: how to deploy to two folders?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, deployment, composer-php

**The general question is: how to work with many different git repos at the same time in one intellij project. Where the git repos need to be inside the main application (that is one git repo too). I cannot use symlinks because I cannot commit those**

I have 2 git repos

one is for the main app, the other one is for a library I am using in several projects.

Here is how it goes: I have the main app. Via composer I add my library / package to the application.

The problem:

folder structure:

to develop

`IdeaProjects/myappA`

note: there is are as well IdeaProjects `myappB` etc

`IdeaProjects/mylib`

in myappA there is

`IdeaProjects/myappA/vendor/mylib`

server deploy folder:

`/var/www/www.myappA.com/`

I do *a lot* of changes to the library, I have it open as another module when I work on `myappA` so I do code changes to `mylib` in that folder / module that actually contains the original source code of `mylib`. Now i don't want to composer install or update each time I do a tiny change. So what I do is I deploy via intellij the files from the library `mylib` each time on save directly into the composer install folder of my main application e.g. to `IdeaProjects/myappA/vendor/mylib`. Now the problem is, I need to deploy it *as well* to the server deployment folder. But there seems no way to deploy files to two folders out of the box with intellij.

What else can I do?

currently I manually use a short key to trigger an ant build that then copies the folder `IdeaProjects/myappA/vendor/mylib` to the server deployment directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple solutions depending on your setup:

solution inside intellij: just import mylib as a module inside your myapp project
Go to `File > Project Settings > Modules`, click the `+` and choose `import module`
[image: import module]

git native solution: Use [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

> Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.

Note that there are some quirks when working with submodules, especially the way to keep the referenced submodules up-to-date

For completeness: if you were using gradle or maven instead of ant, you could use their respective projects views and use the `+` to add multiple build.gradle or pom.xml files, which would automatically import those projects as modules into intellij.

Comment: importing it as intellij module does open new issues. E.g.: I now have the module. The module is the lib. The lib must as well be inside the main project AND the deploy folder. So again: how do I deploy when I change something in the module, to 2 folders?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your setup correctly here.
Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: I have a folder `IdeaProjects/myappA` all source code sits there. I have a deploy folder `/var/www/myappA` all deployed code that runs on my local dev server, sits there.  I have a lib that I code on `IdeaProjects/mylib` each time I make a change in `mylib` I need the changes to be copied to `IdeaProjects/myappA/vendor` and to `/var/www/myappA/vendor`

Comment: I would try to keep both processes separate.

The intellij setup can be handled with any of the suggestions I made and shouldn't copy any files over. There should just be module dependencies making this work.

For the changes needing to be copied to your deployment folder, I would just have the build script do that, or set up an rsync to make it happen if you are certain that 'any' changes can go there at all times (seems kind of risky to me though).

Comment: I actually use git deploy, so if the module is not in the `myappA` folder, then it won't get deployed.
in what way do you deploy to your local dev deployment folder if not any changes? ah maybe I am not sure how rsync works. Will it delete files that exist on the target deployment folder? e.g. i might upload to the local dev folder but not into my src project

Comment: I'm not a php developer myself, so I'm not sure about the specifics of your situation. rsync does not delete any files by default. See https://superuser.com/a/730674 for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the module approach does fit your case and yes you can have a different git repo per module. Right click on your project root `new->module` or `file->new module from existing source`

Intellij should also detect every git repository automatically in your project if you check `Settings | Version Control` you should see the list.

You can also speed up some operations such as `git pull` instead of having to pull from every repository (`VCS -> Git -> Pull`) you can do `VCS -> Update Project` or `ctrl-t` (`cmd-t` on mac)

Comment: this doesn't address the issue of having to deploy into 2 separate folders